# Can I use text from my conference poster in my manuscript?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, poster

I presented a poster at a conference last year to gain some feedback on my research. Since then, I have made significant findings and am beginning to write a manuscript. I would like to use some of the text that I wrote for my poster in my manuscript. Since only my abstract for the conference was peer-reviewed, can I use some text from the body of my poster? Or would this be considered duplicate publishing?

Comment: Was the poster published? Typically, poster presentations are not published - so no risk of duplicate publishing.

Answer (score 6):

This is totally fine. Similarly there’s no harm in using the same text verbatim in a paper and a talk you give about that paper. As long as it’s all clearly part of the development of the same paper there’s just nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

I agree - this will be absolutely fine, unless the presentations given at the conference are to be published as a collective and you are required to publish in order to attend. This is more common in some than in other fields and would be always good to check before you commit to presenting at a meeting.